# If direct mapping scheme was used instead what will be the size of the tag field?

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu-cache

A computer has a 32K main memory and a 4K fully associative cache memory. The block size is 8 words. The access time for main memory is 10 times that of main memory.

a.  What is the size of tag field
b.  If direct mapping scheme was used instead what will be the size of the tag field?

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help with conceptual questions but we're not here to answer homework-style exercises.

Answer (score 0):

Main memory bits = $log_2(32k)$ = 15 bits
Cache size = 4k
Block size = 8 words

**Associate mapping:**

The data  from any location in RAM can be stored in any location in cache.

Associate mapping addressing will be in the form:

\begin{array} {|r|r|}
\hline
Tag &Offset\\
\hline
\end{array}

where,
offset bit = $log_2(block size)$
Tag = Main memory address bit - offset bit

Here,
Offset = $log_28$ = 3 bits
Tag = 15 - 3 =12 bits

\begin{array} {|r|r|}
\hline
12 &3\\
\hline
Tag &Offset\\
\hline
\end{array}

**Direct mapping:**

Each location in RAM has one specific place in cache where the data will be held.

Direct mapping addressing will be in the form:

\begin{array} {|r|r|}
\hline
Tag &line &Offset\\
\hline
\end{array}

where,
offset bit = $log_2(block size)$
line bit = $log_2(cache size/block size)$
Tag = Main memory address bit - (line bit + offset bit)

Here,
Offset = $log_28$ = 3 bits
line = $log_2(4k/8)$ = 9 bits
Tag = 15 - (9+3) = 3 bits

\begin{array} {|r|r|}
\hline
3 &9 &3\\
\hline
Tag &line &Offset\\
\hline
\end{array}

**Answer:**
(a) 12 bits
(b) 3 bits

Recommended lecture notes on cache memory addressing by:

[University of Washington](http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse378/09wi/lectures/lec16.pdf)
[University of Minnesota](https://www.d.umn.edu/~gshute/arch/cache-addressing.xhtml)
[North Carolina A&T State University](http://williams.comp.ncat.edu/comp375/CacheMapping.pdf)

Comment: Please consider not to encourage [undesirable posting behaviour](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594).